# Looking for a computer program or method to list all weekday / Shabbat no-El_Maleh days

Tags: product-recommendation, calendar, tachanun, yahrtzeit

My shul has asked me to compile an annual list of all days when "El Maleh" (prayer said for yahrtzeit) is omitted.

People in my shul know that it is said any day the Torah is read, meaning Mon., Thurs, and Shabbat mincha. Generally, El Maleh would be omitted on a day Tachanun is not said, or in the case of Shabbat mincha, it would include if Tachanun is omitted on the following day (e.g. Erev Rosh Hodesh.)

I need the lsit to include both the Hebrew and English date and the reason it is omitted (e.g. - Rosh Hodesh, Chanukah, during Nissan, etc.)

For the past few years, I created an Excel sheet and did this manually. I'd like to keep this in an easy to read list / column format such as Excel rather than in a calendar program such as Outlook.

I think Hebcal or MyZmanim can produce a list like this, but I'm not sure. I need something that, ideally, I can import into Excel, even if this involves some export / import / converting from a text format, etc.

Can someone recommend a program / method available that can do this?

Comment: Does it need to have preferences about certain days where some omit Tachanun and some don't (eg. Yom Yerushalayim)?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Good question. I didn't consider that. It would be nice. But, if not, I can manually add those unusual exceptions.

Comment: If someone writes a script for you, say in python or perl, can you run it?

Comment: @msh210 - While I have heard of these 2 languages, I have no knowledge of either one to be able to run it unless I had fairly explicit instructions.

Comment: Here seems like  a place to start for writing a program: https://www.hebcal.com/home/195/jewish-calendar-rest-api

Comment: Can you share your manual excel file? I'm trying to see if I can come up with something and it would help to have your list of reasons, i.e. titles of the days it's omitted.

Comment: Can it be a general list of days tachanun is not recited?

Comment: @andrewmh20 I'm not seeking a general list of rules. I know this. I'm trying to find something that can calculate this for each particular year and display / print the list. Ideally, it would be nice if it could include both the Judaic and corresponding Gregorian dates. It's been a long time since I viewed this question, but I think that Hebcal and / or myzmanim comes fairly close to what I need. I think one of them puts a list of non-tachanun days in text format and I can import it into Excel and / or Outlook.

Comment: @DanF  I know; I meant a list of all days tachanun is not recited (with dates) rather than just Mondays Thursdays and shabbos.

Comment: @andrewmh20 Yes, that would work, as long as it's relatively easy for me to delete the extra ones. IIRC, Hebcal does this. However, it has one notable deficiency. El Maleh is said whenever the Torah is read, which includes Shabbat afternoon. Days that are "Erev X" (e.g., Erev Lag Ba'omer on Shabbat afternoon) would also eliminate Tachanun, and thus El Maleh. IIRC, Hebcal can't determine this.

Comment: @andrewmh20 Just browsing. I'll see if I can locate that Excel file and figure a way to share it on a Google drive or similar.